# I have to send checkbox values to my email

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox

I have to send checkbox values to my email. Now, I'm really, really, REALLY new to php, so I need help. On the page where checkboxes are I have a basic form
(your name, last name, phone number, and address) that is also sent to an email, using PHPMailer. But now I have to send that form and checkbox values as a one mail. I already have HTML code for checkboxes and that basic form, and php code to send that form, but I don't know how to include checbox values to that php code. Can anybody help?

My HTML:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once'helpers/security.php';
$errors=isset($_SESSION['errors'])?$_SESSION['errors']:[];
$fields=isset($_SESSION['fields'])?$_SESSION['fields']:[];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Top Food-Smuti sam svoj smoothie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
<img src="tel.png" class="tel"><span class="broj">060 399 333 6</span> | <img src="email.png" class="mail"> <span class="email">topfoodbgd@gmail.com | <img src="lokacija.png" class="lokacija"> <span class="ulica">Knjeginje Zorke 2</span> | <img src="clock.png" class="sat"><span class="vreme"> 11:00-19:00 | </span> <span class="follow">Pratite nas:</span> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Top-Food-407570532782168/"><img src="facebook3.png" class="fb"></a>  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/topfoodbgd/?hl=sr"><img src="instagram3.png" class="in"></a>  <a href="https://twitter.com/TopFoodBGD"><img src="twitter3.png" class="tw"></a>
</header>
    <div class="a">
     <div class="b"> 
         <ul>
             <li><a href="index.php">Dostava obroka</a></li>
             <li><a href="Dostava firme.html">Dostava obroka firmama</a></li>
             <li><a href="ketering za svecane prilike.html"> Ketering za svečane prilike</a></li>
             <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="Djumbir" value="Djumbir" class="sam">Đumbir<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Spanac" value="Spanac" class="sam">Spanać<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Brokoli" value="Brokoli" class="sam">Brokoli<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Kelj" value="Kelj" class="sam">Kelj<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Crveni pasulj" value="Crveni pasulj" class="sam">Crveni pasulj<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Cvekla" value="Cvekla" class="sam">Cvekla<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Celer" value="Celer" class="sam">Celer<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Sargarepa" value="Sargarepa" class="sam">Šargarepa<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Limeta" value="Limeta" class="sam">Limeta<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Krastavac" value="Krastavac" class="sam">Krastavac</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Zelena jabuka" value="Zelena jabuka" class="smoothie">Zelena jabuka<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Avokado" value="Avokado" class="smoothie">Avokado<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Banana" value="Banana" class="sam">Banana<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Malina" value="Malina" class="sam">Malina<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Pomorandza" value="Pomorandza" class="sam">Pomorandža<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Mango" value="Mango" class="sam">Mango<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Aronija" value="Aronija" class="sam">Aronija<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Ananas" value="Ananas" class="sam">Ananas<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Badem" value="Badem" class="sam">Badem<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Orah" value="Orah" class="sam">Orah<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Ovsene pahuljice" value="Ovsene pahuljice" class="sam">Ovsene pahuljice<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Semenke bundeve" value="Semenke bundeve" class="sam">Semenke bundeve<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Chia seme" value="Chia seme" class="sam">Chia seme<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Lan" value="Lan" class="sam">Lan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Cimet" value="Cimet" class="sam">Cimet<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Mirođija" value="Mirođija" class="sam">Mirođija<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Rukola" value="Rukola" class="sam">Rukola<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Nana" value="Nana" class="sam">Nana<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Cimet" value="Cimet" class="sam">Cimet<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Kokosovo ulje" value="Kokosovo ulje" class="sam">Kokosovo ulje<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Agava sirup" value="Agava sirup" class="sam">Agava sirup<br/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact">
                <div class="panel">
                    <?php if(!empty($errors)):?>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <ul><li><?php echo implode('</li> <li>', $errors)?></li></ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                    </p>Zelite da porucite nesto od ovih proizvoda? Popunite formu i mi cemo pozvati vas!</p>
                <form action="contact4.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Ime *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Upisite ime" <?php echo isset ($fields['name'])? 'value="'.e($fields['name']).'"':''?>>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Prezime *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Upisite prezime"<?php echo isset ($fields['email'])? 'value="'.e($fields['email']).'"':''?>>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="email">Broj telefona *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="comment" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Upisite broj telefona"<?php echo isset ($fields['comment'])? 'value="'.e($fields['comment']).'"':''?>>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="message">Adresa* </label>
                    <input type="text" name="message" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Upisite adresu"<?php echo isset ($fields['message'])? 'value="'.e($fields['message']).'"':''?>>
                     <br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Naruci" class="form-control" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                    <p class="muted">* oznacava obavezno polje</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors =[];

if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'],$_POST['comment'])){
    $fields=[
        'ime'=>$_POST['name'],
        'prezime'=>$_POST['email'],
        'broj telefona'=>$_POST['comment'],
        'adresa'=>$_POST['message']
    ];
    foreach($fields as $field=>$data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[]='Polje '.$field . ' je obavezno ';
        }
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        $m=new PHPMailer;
        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth=true;
        $m->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username='';//replace with your email address
        $m->Password='';//replace with your password
        $m->SMTPSecure='ssl';
        $m->Port=465;

        $m->isHTML();
        $m->Subject ='Porudzbina';
        $m->Body='Od: '.$fields['ime'].' '.$fields['prezime'].'<p>Adresa: '.$fields['adresa'].'</p> <p>Broj telefona: '.$fields['broj telefona'].'</p>';

        $m->FromName='Musterija';
        $m->AddAddress('pavles643@gmail.com','Some one');
        if ($m->send()) {
            header('Location:thanks.php');
            die();
        }else{
            $errors[]="Zao nam je sada ne mozemo da pošaljemo porudžbinu, molimo pokušajte kasnije.";
        }
    }
}else{
    $errors[]= 'Nešto je pošlo naopako.';
}
$_SESSION['errors']=$errors;
$_SESSION['fields']=$fields;
header ('Location:smuti sam svoj smoothie.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Safe way:**

```
if(isset($_POST['Brokoli'])) //input named Brokoli will be set if user ticks it
{
   $selected[] = "brokoli";
}
```

OR

```
$included = array("Brokoli", "Blablabla");
$selected = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   if(in_array($key, $included))
   {
        $selected[] = $key;
   }
}
```

(You can use shorthand if as well, but you said you are new to PHP so I don't want to make it complicated)

**Fast way:** (probably not secure)

```
$excluded = array("name", "surname");
$selected = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   if(!in_array($key, $excluded))
   {
        $selected[] = $key;
   }
}
```

This is not secure, because user can change the POST data as they want.

After preparing the array, you can use this to make it string

```
$str = implode($selected, " - "); //example output: Brokoli - Blablabla - Something
```

And implement to mail body string like this

```
$mail->Body = "some text here.. Selected boxes: " . $str;
```

Comment: I tried both safe and fast ways and I can't get this to work. I don't even know if I did everything right. Would it be too much to ask just to copy my PHP code and add everything(one or two items from the checkbox list will be enought just to see what I'm  doing wrong).

Comment: @Pavle can you post output of print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to print the array of checkboxes.

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $selection) {
   echo $selection;
}
```